# How print last commit info for every file in a git repository

Tags: git, bash

I have a script that copies some files from a git repository of mine on a remote server.
For every file that is copied, if it is under version control, I want to generate a line, like:

```
Filename: <filename>, commit: <last-commit-hash>, date: <date of last commit>
```

The idea is to store these lines in a file and copy it as well on the remote server. This way I can always know which file on the server belongs to which commit on my git repository.
Is there a quick way to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm dubious about how useful this will be, since you can always get the information from a local repository, or through gitweb, but here you are:

```
git ls-files | while read file; do git log -n 1 --pretty="Filename: $file, commit: %h, date: %ad" -- $file; done
```

The `%h` gives you an abbreviated hash; if you want the full one, use `%H`. You can also fiddle with the format of the date using `--date=local|iso|rfc|short` (see the [git-log manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)).

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick.
Why it isn't useful? I don't copy my .git directory in my remote server. What is copied are some selected html and javascript file I want to "publish" in my webserver.

Comment: If the server doesn't have a repository, what good does a commit hash do you? And even the date seems iffy - so this file was changed three weeks ago. How? You rewrote the whole thing, or fixed a typo in a comment? Seems like in most practical cases, you'll immediately want to go back to the real repository and see what really changed.

Comment: I have this html/javascript demo. I publish it on my site to make people play with it, meanwhile I keep on developing on it. Since it's an early demo, I don't want to use tags; as I publish every two days, I would have a massive amount of tags, and it would get confusing. I just update the demo everytime I feel it's a bit stable.
Everytime someone finds a bug or a problem, though, I want to know exactly what version are my "published" files, so I can compare them to my HEAD and see if it's a bug I already fixed or not.

Comment: @janesconference: So all you really care about is the commit you published. That one hash is completely sufficient to show you what version of every file is there. `git checkout <sha1>` to get your whole working tree back to that state, or `git show <sha1>:<path>` to see the contents of one file.

Comment: @janesconference: Or, to compare, `git diff <published-commit> HEAD <file>`. There's really no need to know the last time it changed.

Comment: mmh.. you're right. I was erroneously thinking that if I commit, say, file1, then I commit file2 two days later, and then push everything to the remote repository, the commit hash of the last commit alone (in which I committed file2) would refer only to the changes I made in file2 (and not in file1). I was wrong, wasn't I?

Comment: @janesconference: Yeah, git isn't like cvs/svn with their revision numbers. A commit is the whole shebang: some metadata, and a reference to, essentially, a snapshot of the entire work tree. (There are internal details, but they're not important now.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I come from svn and I still struggle on some basic git issues.

Answer (score 8):

I had a chat about this on `#git` with a few guys, and one of them (thanks Mikachu) found [this Perl script](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/e/x/a/ExampleScripts_6d49.html) which had the right algorithm but some serious implementation flaws.

So I fixed up the issues with that script, tidied it up a lot, and [here is the result](https://github.com/aspiers/git-config/blob/master/bin/git-ls-dir) (download from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspiers/git-config/master/bin/git-ls-dir)).  Note that it currently requires `Term::ANSIColor` to run. here you can see a screenshot of it in action:

[image: screenshot of git-ls-dir runs]
<sub>(source: [adamspiers.org](http://adamspiers.org/computing/git-ls-dir.png))</sub>

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is faster and can be sorted by age:

```
find <dir> -exec git log -n 1 --pretty="%ai {}" "{}" \; | sort -r
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as it does not produce any Git commit info.

Comment: And at no point is it showing the results of `git log`. Each line it prints looks like `2019-03-08 17:20:47 +0100 ./keymaps/henrebotha/keymap.c`, which doesn't contain a commit hash, a branch name, or anything else related to Git.